# Get a list of API calls to the Salesforce System

Tags: rest-api, api, soap-api

Is there any way to do this within SFDC or do I have to go through support?

I am trying to get a list of API calls that are made to SFDC, the number of calls made and the entity that made the call. e.g. google.com makes a call to our salesforce instance 300k times and they made the call "get leads" 150k times and "update leads" 150k times

Comment: as a workaround to @AsifK's answer, I tend to use unique users for each API client so I can use normal SFDC reports and login history to get a sense of activity by client. Not a perfect answer to your question but maybe good enough for your purposes

Answer (score 1):

Eventlogfile object provides granular api call information: This link has more info [EventLogFile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm)

At a high level, total api calls in last 24 hours can be seen at this path Setup => Company Profile => Company Information => API Requests, Last 24 Hours

Refer to this link for more info about API call limits and Reporting
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000003706&language=en_US